# Postgres : Post statement (or insert) asynchronous, non-blocking processing

Tags: events, postgresql, concurrency, asynchronous, nonblocking

I'm wondering if it is possible, that after a collection of rows is inserted, to initiate an operation that is executed asynchronously, is non-blocking, and doesn't need to inform the originator of the request - of the result.

I am working with large amounts of events and I can guarantee that the post-insert logic will not fail -- I just want to have a single insert thread in my event-sources, and I want this thread to keep flying without blocking, and without being responsible for any post-delivery book-keeping.

I can tell you that I would potentially have a 100 of these jobs executing concurrently  and each job might operate on 5 tables with anywhere between 200-1000 inserts on each of these tables.

A hint in the right direction should be enough.

Comment: can you tell me how did you solve this issue? usually this is a task i would do with dbms_job /schedule in oracle, but i am missing this feature in pg. so i came across this very old thread have a very similar question ...

Comment: I'm writing my own data processing engine :D

Comment: thx for info. I use dblink_send_query right now. But my "problem" is, that I have to make sure the connection which is triggering the trigger have to be open until every dblink query has finished.

Answer (score 3):

[LISTEN/NOTIFY](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/libpq-notify.html) might be what you need, have a listener on a separate connection run a *LISTEN notifyname* (it can use a nonblocking socket and use *poll*, or however your application is working), and your code run *NOTIFY notifynam*e after it is processed, but you will need some way for your LISTENing thread to know what record was completed, perhaps with a log table of some kind.  Also worth noting is that libpq supports [asynchronous mode](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/libpq-async.html) (which is supported, at least, by [DBD::Pg](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBD-Pg), presumably other Pg drivers too).

Answer (score 0):

I will add somehow different answer.

You could use Redis to temporarily store your requests and then you can batch process them every X seconds. (at least you can do insert of multiple rows at once - usually you can do way more ...).

Maybe it is time to check Kafka or Amazon's Kinesis. It is more advanced service which lets you do something similar as I mentioned above.

Answer (score -1):

Since you are actually just simply batch processing a large amount of rows, why not let a cron job post process the rows when you're done with them?

Just mark them as non-processed (or redirect them to a processing table with a trigger) and process them all at once when you're done.

Comment: The data is coming in non-stop :/

Comment: How about creating a cronjob that replaces the trigger used for inserting every `n` minutes.
THat way you could write to a new table every `n` minutes and after replacing the trigger you would process the previous table and write it to the actual destination table.

Comment: That is a possibility, I will have to mull this over -- perhaps blocking from the client, and writing directly to the target tables, is a better choice. At least the complexity characteristics will be well defined.